# Check, if A ~ B have a relation

Tags: linear-algebra, relations

Let

$$A \sim B \iff \exists v \in \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \left(
\begin{array}{c}
0\\
0\\
\end{array}
\right) 
: \mathcal{L}_{A,v} \cap \mathcal{L}_{B,v} \neq \emptyset$$

be a relation on $\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$. $\mathcal{L}_{A,b}$ is defined as $\{ x \in \mathbb{R^n}: Ax = b\}$.

Now check if $\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0\\
\end{array}
\right) $ and $\left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0\\
0 & 1\\
\end{array}
\right) $ are in relation to each other.

Given all of this, my conclusion is that I need to check if $Ax = Bx$, right? Since both $x$ are the same, this means I just need to check if $A=B$?

Comment: No, you need to check if there *exists* some $x$ such that $Ax=Bx\neq 0$.

Comment: So essentially $(A-B)x = 0$, but this results in the same statement $A=B$, doesn't it?

Comment: Not at all, I don't know why you would think that. A matrix $M$ can satisfy $Mx=0$ for some $x$ without being the zero matrix.